# What kind of past habit fits this text? "were always doing" or "used to do"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, would, used-to

As I understand it, there are three ways to explain past habits:

- Would
- Past continuous
- Used to

According to that, what is the best form of past habits for the following text?

> My sister and I had a wonderful childhood. We grew up in the country, and we made the most of it. There was a special place in the woods where we would play every day. Lots of wildflowers grew there, and we would pick lots of them to take home. It seems like we (**were always doing** / **used to do**) something outside.

Could someone explain which one is correct and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*It seemed like we were always*

- *playing outside*
- *in detention*
- *off on some trip or other*
- *involved in some escapade or other*
  ....

(note the evaluation here is also set back in the past, 'seemed')

is the usual way of showing the mindset of foregrounding prominent memories (so that regular events are promoted hyperbolically to durative consideration).

Only the first example above uses the past continuous, though.

................

Your own 'There was a special place in the woods where we would play every day.' shows a perfectly fine example of the use of 'would' to show the habitual past. But using 'would' after 'it seemed like' forces an irrealis sense, so not a choice.

................

'It seems/ed like we used to ...' [play, etc] defaults to a concessive statement, again not what is required.

Comment: As usual, good analysis. I ran into this sentence some time back and because it seems to be somewhat pertinent to OP's question, I would like you to weigh in on what's happening here: _Many years later, as he **faced** the firing squad, Colonel Aureliano Buendía **was to remember** that distant afternoon when his father took him to discover ice._  What if *would* replaced *was to remember*? I'm not sure how that changes the meaning.

Comment: Both totally grammatical and idiomatic in a formal setting; no difference in denotation. The different nuance is that 'was to remember' has more immediacy (rather like the use of the historic/narrative/dramatic present), highlighting a reported completed event in the past (from the perspective of the narrator) rather than looking forward to 'many years later'.

Answer (score -1):

The difference is one of frequency, intensity or emphasis. "used to do" implies a lower degree of at least those one of things than "were always doing".

For example we could say "We used to go to Brighton for our holidays every year" or "We were always going to Brighton" but the first of these implies that you went there once a year while the second implies much more frequent visits.

Also we could say "We used to have porridge for breakfast every day" or "We were always having porridge for breakfast". In this case the first one states explicitly that porridge was a routine element of breakfast with the implication that it was accepted, and possibly remembered fondly but the second implies that porridge was less fondly remembered and, probably, was not a daily occurrence. This is an example of the use of the phrase to carry both intensity and intensity.

In fact we would never use "We were always doing" to describe routine, habitual practice. We would always use "We used to do". For example we would not say "We were always going to Brighton for our holidays every year" or "We would always be having porridge for breakfast every day" because both of those actions are defined as routine and habitual by the specification of the time elements.

Comment: I have to disagree. The choice in OP’s case is not made due to a difference in frequency.   And “We were always having porridge for breakfast” seems perfectly natural.

Comment: @Jim Is that to say both are correct?

Comment: @Jim I didn't say that it wasn't perfectly natural, it is. It's just that it means something different from "We used to have porridge for breakfast". "We used to have porridge for breakfast" implies that there were very few, if any, days when they _didn't_ have porridge but "We were always having porridge for breakfast" implies that there were many days when breakfast was porridge but that there  were some days when they did not. This isn't true in Irish dialect, however, where "We were always having" seems to mean a routine, habitual, practice.

Comment: @SirwanAfifi Both are correct, it's just that, in my experience as a British English speaker, there is a subtle but important difference in meaning.

Comment: I don't see a difference in frequency, both are very dependent on context but mean frequently, usually or almost always, with "were always" not meaning literally all the time. The difference is rather that "used to" implies you stopped, while "were always" could mean you do it less frequently now.

Comment: @SirwanAfifi - No.  Only “were always doing” fits in your example.    While both are grammatical only one works here.